# Manipulating soap evelope in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

For a project we are connecting to the KVK Handelsregister DataService from the Netherlands. We have setup a WCF client proxy class, however our soap envelope still differs from the envelope they requested, any idea's to solve these 3 problems:

1. Remove the mustUnderstandAttribute
2. The body has no namespace in the elements (ns:)
3. The header also does not have the reference to OASIS

Our envelope:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://es.kvk.nl/genereerProduct</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:173035b3-714d-46ef-96c2-1d46962ec897</a:MessageID>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="3d2fb1c7-99db-4c88-9745-6cd187281fc6" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">5f48b058-21d5-46c4-8a8b-02f60556ef0e</ActivityId>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://es.kvk.nl/KVK-DataserviceCT/2012/10</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <genereerProduct xmlns="http://schemas.kvk.nl/schemas/hrip/generiekproduct/2013/01">
      <productRequest>
        <klantreferentie>QW43BA12</klantreferentie>
        <productnaam>Inschrijving</productnaam>
        <productsleutel>
          <kvkNummer>01048900</kvkNummer>
        </productsleutel>
      </productRequest>
    </genereerProduct>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The envelope as it should be

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:ns="http://schemas.kvk.nl/schemas/hrip/generiekproduct/2013/01" 
xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <soapenv:Header>
                        <add:Action>http://es.kvk.nl/genereerProduct</add:Action>
                        <add:MessageID>uuid://94-b0e0-d4313c898af0</add:MessageID>
                        <add:To>http://es.kvk.nl/KVK-DataserviceCT/2012/10</add:To>
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body>
                        <ns:genereerProduct>
                                    <ns:productRequest>
                                                <ns:klantreferentie>QW43BA12</ns:klantreferentie>
                                                <ns:productnaam>Inschrijving</ns:productnaam>
                                                <ns:productsleutel>
                                                            <ns:kvkNummer>01048900</ns:kvkNummer>
                                                </ns:productsleutel>
                                    </ns:productRequest>
                        </ns:genereerProduct>
            </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>*
```

As requested below in comments the binding configuration for both the wsHttpBinding and customBinding. Changing this has no influence on the soap envelope, the error with the custom binding is:

> ERROR An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   https://webservices
>   8.kvk.nl/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context
>   being aborted by the  server (possibly due to the service shutting
>   down). See server logs for more de tails.

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ProductServiceSoap11">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />

      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="WsHttpSoap11" >
      <transactionFlow />
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"  />
      <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true"  />

    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: your bullet 2 is not a problem because the namespace is *inlined* on your `genereerProduct` element

Comment: i indeed would think the same thing, but I am still not sure what software is used on the service (certainly not WCF from microsoft on server side), and maybe they do some manual parsing, because they also use the To parameter in the header to do some internal routing

Comment: I think you need [MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageversion.soap12wsaddressing10(v=vs.90).aspx) on your textMessageEncoder. Do you have a custombinding?

Comment: no i have to use wsHttpBinding for the certificates, and because the to is different from the url of the service i have to use clientVIa, and i can't get those 2 things working in a customBinding ;-(

Comment: I have had difficulties to have the wsHttpBinding behave with java based backends which is what the KVK uses if I recall correctly. You need to configure a custombinding. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347793(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is this a digi-koppeling endpoint?

Comment: this is the link i am setting up: http://www.kvk.nl/producten-bestellen/handelsregister-dataservice/ , because i do not exactly understand what you mean bu digi :-)

Comment: I think we need to see your binding config as well, both the wsHttpBinding as the customBinding that failed for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I found the correct configuration and got this link working. After all fiddling with the SOAP envelope was merely a part of the whole solution for this connection.

But i'll add some info, that helped me a lot in getting this working.

1) logging, add this to you config file to get logging going

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
    propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="c:\\TestKVKService\TestKVKService\bin\Debug\Log\Tracesmore.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
    name="xml" />
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true" />
```

2) And add this to your serviceModel tag. Be sure to enable all messages and certainly **logMessagesAtTransportLevel** because then you will see how your message is sent over the wire.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging
       logEntireMessage="true"
       logMalformedMessages="true"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
       maxMessagesToLog="3000"
       maxSizeOfMessageToLog="64000"/>
</diagnostics>
```

3) And the final config file looked like this

- **MutualCertificate**: because the message was signed before sending, and signed when receveived, with 2 different credentials, but that is
  specified in the endpoint biding
- **messageProtectionOrder**: to make wcf encrypt and sign the messages
- **defaultAlgorithmSuite**: because .NET uses other algorithms than this java server
- **allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply**: because the response was also signed
- **requireClientCertificate**: to sent the client certificate to the server
- **ExInspector**: needed to manipulate the TO in the envelope
- **clientVia**: because it is talking to an intermediate router

And last but not lease: this server was sending me back empty actions, so I had to fiddle with the generated proxy class.

```
     <bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="WsHttpSoap11" >
      <transactionFlow />
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"  />
      <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" 
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10"
                 messageProtectionOrder="EncryptBeforeSign"
                defaultAlgorithmSuite="TripleDesRsa15" 
                allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" >
      </security>
      <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true"   />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://other-endpoint-then-servername" binding="customBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WsHttpSoap11" contract="ProductService"
          name="ProductServiceSoap11" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehaviour">
    <identity>
      <dns value="serverdnsname" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="ExInspector" type="TestService.ExClientBehaviorExtensionElement, TestService"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myServiceBehaviour">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="clientcertificatename" storeLocation="CurrentUser" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeName="My" />
        <serviceCertificate >
          <defaultCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" findValue="servercertificatename" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"  />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
      <clientVia viaUri="https://serverdnsname" />
      <ExInspector />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

If any questions about the topic feel free to contact me. And look through this blog, it helped me a lot: http://webservices20.blogspot.be/2012/06/12-common-wcf-interop-confusions.html